# Laravel Doesn't Use the Right Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Laravel picks the wrong table, the `users` table. I have switched the table in `config/auth` to the correct one but for some reason, Laravel still uses the default `users` table.

**Code**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserLoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $table = 'pupil';

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:3'
        ]);

        $user = User::where('accountName', $request->user)
            ->where('password', $request->password)
            ->first();

        if ($user) {
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect()->route('neue_anmeldung');
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput('email');
    }
}
```

I get the following error message.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'database1.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where
>   `accountName` = 6001 and `password` = password limit 1)

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: You uses User Model thats why it's searching a users table mention your Model name carefully

Comment: so i have to rename My Users.php in app/ to the table i want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` model is configured to use the `users` table. You have defined the table in your `controller` which is wrong. You need to define the property `protected $table = 'pupil';` in your `App\User.php`

Answer (score 0):

By default `eloquent` Will assumes the tables as follows

`For Example`

If Your Model name is

`User` Then it will search for `users`  table in database

`AdminUser` Then it will search for `admin_users`  table in database

To Change the default `tablename` assumed by `eloquent`

Open Your Current Model

**`Not Your Controller`** 
and `protected $table = 'yourTableNAme';`

Hope it helps